# IPYTHON: adding a new folder to searchable template locations for `nbconvert`

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

The IPYTHON [documentation](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/api/generated/IPython.nbconvert.exporters.templateexporter.html#module-IPython.nbconvert.exporters.templateexporter) implies there is a way to modify the config file to include an additional path for templates.

Please advise. I have a template file which I want to use, with extension **.tpl* which I do not want to have to move around to the local directory of where I do my work.

Any tips? I've searched everywhere and can't find this. It seems to only search the local directory where I am running the `ipython nbconvert test.ipynb --to slides --template output_toggle_html`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `ipython_nbconvert_config.py` file located , you can enter the line `c.TemplateExporter.template_path = ['.']` which will do the same as the default behavior, however you can add to this list.  For example, the code below adds `$IPYTHONDIR/nbextensions/templates` and will search for `*.tpl` files in those locations, in the order in which they are provided in the list.

```
from os import environ
IPYTHONDIR = environ["IPYTHONDIR"]
template_rel_path = '/nbextensions/templates'
template_path = IPYTHONDIR + template_rel_path
c.TemplateExporter.template_path = [
                                '.',
                                template_path
                                    ]
```